# Is it too broken to house rule that the spell Healing Elixir heals an additional d4 per slot level used?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, balance, house-rules

Is it too broken to house rule that the spell *Healing Elixir* (from [Unearthed Arcana: Starter Spells](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf)) heals an additional d4 per slot level used? It's practically half the Cure Wounds Spell in a physical format. Does the fact that you can spam this spell throughout the day with a Warlock and that Elixir has a 24 hour duration make it and unfair advantage to any group?

Comment: The last sentence is very hard to understand, and it seems to be an important part of what you’re asking. Could you [edit] to explain that sentence more clearly?

Comment: What do you mean by broken?

Comment: What do you mean by *spamming* the spell, given the limited number of Warlock spells prepared and spell slots.

Comment: I think one of the concerns from the asker is: Warlock uses all their spell slots on *healing elixir* before a short rest, then gets to keep those elixirs alongside refreshed spell slots. In theory you could do the same with wizards as well and without the house rule, but with the house rule it scales a lot more than without, and it scales especially well for a Warlock because all their slots are "at" their highest casting level, and they get to dump those slots into elixirs every short rest instead of just long rests.

Comment: @KamilDrakari See my answer. Did you run the numbers on this?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I did not run any numbers, and I did not (intentionally) make claims about whether or not the use that I identified is "broken". I just identified it as a way *healing elixir* differs from other healing spells, thus is potentially relevant to determining its power.

Comment: We still have people trying to guess what your question actually is, which means it’s not clear enough yet to answer or to vote on answers. Could you [edit] to explain *all* the thinking that is part of this question? Sometimes that’s not 100% necessary, but a perfectly clear question is very necessary when the point of the question is when what you’re thinking about house ruling is balanced or not.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the spells in [Unearthed Arcana: Starter Spells](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf) received official status when printed in **Xanathar's Guide to Everything**. "Healing Elixir" was not among them.

The fact that it was excluded is a clear sign from the developers that they believed the spell was flawed or defective in some way. Trying to enhance something the game's own developers rejected, trying to make it more powerful, is probably ill advised.

The points you've raised may very well be part of the logic for it's exclusion, but we're not likely to ever know. Adding effectively free healing to a short rest, a system that's already designed to measure out healing slowly over the adventuring day (in the form of Hit Dice), doesn't seem wise.

Comment: I feel like it is good  to know that the designers opted not to include this spell officially yet, but I also find that leaning on this unknown and undefined reasoning is not very convincing. For all we know, for example, the spell could have been fine, but cut for space ot thematic issues.

Answer (score 2):

### The proposal is not "broken" but it may be ill-advised

Warlock spells slots expended represent an opportunity cost.  Warlocks don't add spell their casting modifier to this healing elixir, as divine casters do.  Why a given spell caster would, in your words, spam healing spells is an open question ... but if that's how your party wants to use its spell casters, go for it.

> Is the fact that you can spam this spell throughout the day with a Warlock and that Elixir has a 24 hour duration make it and unfair advantage to any group?

No, not an unfair advantage.  Here's why.

#### Compare a Spamming Warlock to a Spamming Druid at levels 5 and 9

*Spamming* Definition for this question: use all spell slots available in a day to heal, to the exclusion of other uses of spells.  This should illustrate the comparative healing capacity of a Warlock with a typical divine caster.

Spamming *Assumptions*:

1. The Warlock benefits from two short rests<sup>1</sup>.
2. Moon Druid, so no restoring spell slots during the day
3. Spellcasting ability (Charisma or Wisdom) of 16 and 18 (to be conservative) at levels 5 and 9 respectively.

At level 5, Druid has: 4 1st, 3 2d and 2 3rd.
At level 9, Druid has: 4 1st, 3 2d, 3 3rd, 3 4th, 1 5th.
At Level 5, Warlock has: 2 3rd level slots, total of six per day with two short rests.
At level 9, Warlock has 2 5th level slots, total of six per day with two short rests.

1. Cure Wounds heals: 1d8 + your spellcasting ability modifier. Add 1d8
   for each slot level above 1st at higher levels.
   Druid provides:

   - 16d8 + 27 HP of healing per spell casting day.(45 + 27 = 99) at level 5
   - 36d8 + 56 HP of healing per spell casting day (162 + 56 = 218) at level 9
2. Elixer: the drinker regains 2d4 + 2 hit points. Add 1d4 per spell slot above first.
   Warlock provides:

   - (2d4+2 + 2d4) x 6 = 72 HP of healing per spell casting day at level 5
   - (2d4+2 +4d4) x6 = 102 HP of healing per spell casting day at level 9

Hardly broken, but quite possibly a sub-optimal use of Warlock (and Druid) spell slots.  What else could you have used those spell slots for during that adventure day?

---

<sup>1</sup>The Adventure Day standard model (DMG p. 84)

> If it the adventure has more easy encounters, they can get through more. If the adventure has more hard encounters, they can handle fewer. {snip}
> **Short Rests**
> In general, over the course of a full adventuring day, the party will likely need to take two short rests, about one-third and two-thirds of the way through the day.

Answer (score 0):

The healing will always be somewhat minor and consumes an action in combat, so no, I would not consider it a problem, to allow it to scale a little.

The whole: "What if a warlock took 8+ short rests during a day and used the spell slots to do ?", is super trite at this point. Would his party really go for it? And if they do, you as the DM make sure they feel what it means to spend **hours** resting every day... They'll stop doing it soon enough, when they realise the world doesn't wait for them to rest.

If they really wanted to abuse the mechanic with warlocks getting their spell slots back on short rests, there's better uses for it, than making healing potions that last 24 hours...
(Like taking levels in sorcerer, making an insane amount of sorcery points and converting them to spell slots, then casting Animate Dead, oh say, 100 times in a row?)